# Cuda atomic operations

Tags: c++, concurrency, cuda, atomic

I have the following kernel :

```
__global__
void collect_boundary(const int64_t* cvert, const csr_node* neighb, const bool* affected, int64_t* parent, const uint64_t* dist, uint64_t* ndist, bool* mask, int64_t numvertices){
    int64_t tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tid >= numvertices || affected[tid] || dist[tid]==MY_INFINITY)
        return;
    for(int64_t index = cvert[tid]; index<cvert[tid+1]; index++){
        auto vtex = neighb[index];
        if(affected[vtex.head]){
            int64_t ndistent = dist[tid] + vtex.weight; 
            atomicMin((unsigned long long int*)(ndist + vtex.head),(unsigned long long int)ndistent);
            /*if(ndist[vtex.head] == ndistent){
                parent[vtex.head] = tid;
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Basically i wanted each thread to compute ndistent as given and i update ndist[vtex.head] as the minimum of all ndistents.

I achieved this using:

```
atomicMin((unsigned long long int*)(ndist + vtex.head),(unsigned long long int)ndistent);

//That is each thread will update ndist[vtex.head] if and only if
//it's own value of ndistent is less than the ndist[vtex.head] 
//which was initialized to INFINITY before the kernel launch
```

But now i wanted to store the tid which gives the minimum ndistent.

I tried something like this

```
if(ndist[vtex.head] == ndistent){  // prob_condition 1
    parent[vtex.head] = tid;       // prob_statment 1
}

//That is each thread will check wether the value in 
//ndist[vtex.head] is equal to it's own ndistent 
// and then store the tid if it is.
```

This above snippet won't work because some **thread X** may find that prob_condition 1 to be true , but before it executes prob_statement 1 let us say the thread which will give the min value **say thread Y** executes prob_statement 1 and stores it's tid. Now thread X will resume and store it's tid, thus the min tid is lost.

So i want prob_condition 1 and prob_statement 1 to be executed atomically.

Or alternatively i need to do the following 3 opertaions atomically:

1. Check if ndistent < ndist[vtex.head]
2. update ndist[vtex.head]
3. store tid in parent[vtex.head]

Anyone has any suggestions how i can do this?

**EDIT:**
Please note that i will have to run this kernel with variable number of blocks and variable number of threads.

Answer (score 1):

It might not solve your concurrency issue the way you intend it, but you could have a two phases approach: first, compute the min, and then find the guy(s) that have that min.

Also, if several tid have the same ndistent value, the output may vary from one execution to the other, indeed as Taro pointed out, execution order of warps does not obey predicitble rules. That two phases approach may help you build a predictible pattern for the list of minima.

In a more *hacky* approach, if ndistent value and tid can both fit in 64 bits, you may try having high-order bits of a 64bits value fed with ndistent and low-order bits holding the tid, and doing the atomicMin in one instruction.